# Не получается расположить цветные полосы(прямоугольники) в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем доброго времени суток! Я пишу программу выводящую на экран цветные полосы, за основу выбран метод Canvas create_rectangle. Первые две полосы я расположил успешно, но при попытке после второй полосы расположить третью я терплю неудачу т.к третья полоса полностью вторую закрывает и почему-то по размерам не сходится. Я ломал голову, пробовал разные размеры присваивать прямоугольнику, но итог все тот же. Как мне решить эту задачу?

```
import tkinter as tk


def toggle_fs(dummy=None):
    state = False if root.attributes('-fullscreen') else True
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', state)
    if not state:
        root.geometry('300x300+100+100')


root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root)
c.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
rectangle1 = c.create_rectangle(250, 1080, 0, 0, fill='white')
rectangle2 = c.create_rectangle(250, 1080, 550, 0, fill='yellow')
rectangle3 = c.create_rectangle(250, 1080, 750, 0, fill='green')



root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

root.bind('<Escape>', toggle_fs)

root.mainloop()
```

Окно с двумя полосами
[image: Окно с двумя полосами]
Окно с тремя полосами
[image: Окно с тремя полосами]
Такое окно хочу получить
[image: Такое окно хочу получить]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и без использования канваса. Просто накидать в окно фреймов разных цветов. А дальше они сами равномерно заполнят всё пространство.

```
import tkinter as tk

def toggle_fs(dummy=None):
    state = False if root.attributes('-fullscreen') else True
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', state)
    if not state:
        root.geometry('300x300+100+100')

root = tk.Tk()

for color in """
#000000
#0000C0
#C00000
#C000C0
#00C000
#00C0C0
#C0C000
#FFFFFF
""".split():
    tk.Frame(bg=color).pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.bind('<Escape>', toggle_fs)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: -]

Comment: Спасибо за развернутое решение! Это то что я хотел создать, но еще не  знаю о  tk.Frame т.к. нахожусь на начальном этапе изучения Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы первая полоса не закрывала другую переместите её правее:

```
rectangle3 = c.create_rectangle(550, 1080, 750, 0, fill='green')
```

Результат:
[image: Результат]